# Why cant I run my rails app using heroku locally?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a new project that is using heroku, I get this error when I try to run the app locally:

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure at / Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

and I think it has something to do with Heroku because if I type

```
$ heroku info,
```

i get this error:

```
!  You do not have access to the app disrupt.
```

I can't find this error anywhere on the internet, on any forums and there is nothing in the Heroku documentation.

Comment: Have you logged in on Heroku in the command line?

Comment: If I type $ heroku auth:login and get authenticated correctly but then when I try and run $ heroku run rake I get the same error: Running rake attached to terminal... failed ! You do not have access to the app disrupt. – Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error normally just means that the MongoDB server is not running locally. Try starting it up by running `mongod`. Otherwise check you mongoid.yml to see how the development and test environments are set up to connect to MongoDB.

The other error that you get from heroku looks like a separate issue. As tolgap suggests you may just not be authenticated with heroku.

Comment: Thanks for that Steve, I am new to rails! Successfully got mongo set up but the issue is still with heroku. I am type $ heroku auth:login and get authenticated correctly but then when i try and run heroku run rake i get the same error Running `rake` attached to terminal... failed
 !    You do not have access to the app disrupt.

Comment: Sounds like the Heroku app owner has not added you as a collaborator for that particular app. Do you see it when you log in to Heroku in your browser?

Comment: This is why im stuck because I am definitely a collaborator, I can log in to Heroku with me own credentials and I see all 3 apps, dev, staging and production. Is there anything I may have missed? Even something realy simple?

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong then. You can specify the Heroku command line tools in several ways, the HEROKU_APP env variable, an `--app` param or it works it out from you git remotes I think. Do the apps listed `heroku app` match the git remotes listed by `git remote -v`?

Comment: If I type $ heroku apps then I see all 3 apps that I am the collaborator of, it has the owners email next to the app name, is this correct or should it have my email? if I type git remote -v
heroku git@heroku.com:disrupt.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:disrupt.git (push)
origin https://github.com/lomalogue/disrupt.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/lomalogue/disrupt.git (push)